# Trying to run SummitKwan's transparent_latent_gen to generate faces in Google Colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, auto-generate, generative-adversarial-network

I am following [this](https://github.com/SummitKwan/transparent_latent_gan) documentation from Github on how to autogenerate some faces with AI. I'm trying to do it in a Google Colab notebook.

Executing:

```
exec(open('./src/tl_gan/script_generation_interactive.py').read())
```

I am getting this error message:

> ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk'
>   interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running

It should has to do with matplotlib.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Please post the code that you're having a problem with, as well as the environment you're using (is it mac, pc, linux?  python version? etc).  The problem looks like it's related to the matplotlib backend failing - so the info about the environment is pretty key to know.